# How to remove slash in breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: output as picture below]

I am unable to customize php due to php encrypted. It is possible by JavaScript/jQuery?

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<a href="index.php">Home </a> / <a href="about.php">About</a> / <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
```

Comment: It is possible with javascript/jquery. Is it possible for you to paste the markup (as text, not image)?

Comment: Whats wrong, why giving always minus vote? As new user not eligible for posting here? There is image option, so i have posted image for very clarification. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 2):

You could get it done with jQuery and some [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/62UTaD/1).

please note: this is assuming your code does not have `<li>` tags wrapping the `<a>` tags

```js
const regex = /(<\/a>).*?\//g;
const str = $('.breadcrumb').html();
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
$('.breadcrumb').html(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="index.php">Home </a> / <a href="about.php">About</a> / <a href="contact.php">Contact</a> 
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for shared. Its working but the slash showing while page showing at once then hide the slash.

Comment: Well yes. First the HTML loads, then JS loads, `THEN` JS is executed. So it will flick. You may also hide it with css class `hide{opacity:0}` and after the above solution is run, also remove the class with jquery `$('.breadcrumb').removeClass('hide')`. But! it will still flick

Comment: I have applied both method. Another idea?

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery here (note: I would absolutely not use this in production).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb *')
    .forEach(x => x.innerText = x.innerText.replace('/', ''));
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="index.php">Home </a> / </li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a> / </li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>
```

---

Edit: here's a variant that accomodates the utterly wrong HTML markup:

```js
const toArray = (nodeList) => Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);

toArray(document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb'))
    .map    ((node)     => toArray(node.childNodes))
    .reduce ((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
    .filter ((node)     => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
                        && node.textContent.indexOf('/') !== -1)
    .forEach((node)     => node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/\//g, ''));
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="index.php">Home </a> / 
    <a href="about.php">About</a> / 
    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved with css. Note: Your html structure is wrong.

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="index.php">Home </a> 
</li>
<li>
<a href="about.php">About</a> </li><li> <a href="contact.php">Contact</a> </li></ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.breadcrumb{

}
ul.breadcrumb li{
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.breadcrumb li+li:before{
    content:"/";
    display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9q1m0on9/

Comment: What do you mean by i am serious...Do you mean the question or referring to anyother article.

Comment: I mean question